# error in apache karaf after deploying

Tags: apache-karaf

org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:61)
 org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:69)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.execute(BundlesCommand.java:54)[24:org.apache.karaf.bundle.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.action.command.ActionCommand.execute(ActionCommand.java:83)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4
 org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[44:org.apache.karaf.shel
 org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[44:org.apache.karaf.shel
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.5]
 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.
 org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:270)[44:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_40]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you write what you executed on the shell to get this exception? Do you have more in the log? If it was feature:install try the -v option.